# Android detect MediaPlayer buffer update from service class

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-broadcast, android-service-binding

I've implemented a MediaPlayer inside Service class so that the player can be accessed from any activity. Since I can use the MediaPlayer in any Activity so its important to show the buffer update while switching from one activity to another.

To detect the buffer update I've used the OnInfo() method inside service class

```
@Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
            sendBufferStartBroadcast();

        } else if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
            sendBufferCompleteBroadcast();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here sendBufferCompleteBroadcast() & sendBufferStartBroadcast() are two broadcast to check the updated value outside the Service class

To check the update from an Activity class I've used this approach,

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastBufferReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showBufferProgress(intent);
        }
    };

private void showBufferProgress(Intent bufferIntent) {
        String bufferValue = bufferIntent.getStringExtra("buffer_status");
        int bufferStatus = Integer.parseInt(bufferValue);

        switch (bufferStatus) {
        case 0:
            if (progressBar != null) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                changeUI();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't works correctly and whenever I switch from other Activity to another the buffer update gets lots and shows no progress.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this class design. this is not full code. this code is just like pseudo code.

```
public class YourService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener,
    OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    private static WeakReference<SeekBar> songProgressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mp.reset();

        songProgressBar = new WeakReference<SeekBar>(YourActivity.seekBar); // You must declare your seekbar as static at your layout activity
        songProgressBar.get().setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        super.onCreate();

    }        


    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        songProgressBar.get().setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: To be more specific I want to update a progressbar for showing if the song is currently buffering not the seekbar position. If I keep updating the progressbar from onBufferingUpdate() method it will show the progressbar till the buffer finishes 100% which I don't want. @Nazmul Hasan Masum

Comment: You've seen i updated the Secondary Progress which as like youtube buffering progress. i thought that concept may you help. by the way, if you want the buffering condition from any activity if you do not stop the service. you can keep the buffering progress in static variable then checking that static variable from another activity through a runnable thread. already i faced and solved this type of problem by following that way